# ASP.Net Panel JQuery SlideToggle Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net panel with a style which hides it and I'm using JQuery to slideToggle the panel using a hyperlink. This works fine. However, if I add a button on the page that causes a postback the panel will default back to hidden. I understand why this is happening but what is the best way to keep the panels visibility state when a postback occurs?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .panel
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#Link1").click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#panelText').slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">SlideToggle
    </asp:HyperLink><br />
    <asp:Panel ID="panelText" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
        Some text</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Postback" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem...

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .panel
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#Link1").click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#panelText').slideToggle('slow');
                if ($('#panelText').hasClass('panel')) {
                    $('#PanelState').attr('value', 'true');
                } else {
                    $('#PanelState').attr('value', 'false');
                }                
             });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('#PanelState').attr('value') == 'false') {
                $('#panelText').addClass('panel');
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="PanelState" runat="server" Value="false" />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">SlideToggle
    </asp:HyperLink><br />
    <asp:Panel ID="panelText" runat="server">
        Some text</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Postback" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the same. But I want the panel to be hidden on form load. I tried a few things, didnt work. Can you tell me what I need to change ? Excellent answer btw.

Answer (score 4):

Add a hidden field in form:

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="hdnPanelState" runat="Server" value="false" />
```

and modify the JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#Link1").click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('#panelText').slideToggle('slow');
            //YOU WILL ALSO NEED TO CALCULATE IF SHOWING PANEL OR HIDING 
            $("#hdnPanelState").attr("value","true");//Store Value
        });
    });
</script>
```